# Manipulate data before insert using Laminas DB TableGatewayEvent and TableGateway

Tags: php, database, events, laminas

I am trying to manipulate the dataset before performing insert into the actual table using Laminas\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway class. The intention is to force set certain fields such as `created_by` and `created_on` to ensure the value is consistent across the application.
Example:

```
$dataset['created_by'] = App::getUserId();
$dataset['created_on'] = new \DateTime(); // This is just example as Laminas won't accept DateTime object for DateTime field and requires the string format instead. But i suppose you got the point.
```

Understand that i can attach event listener to TableGateway using Laminas\Db\TableGateway\Feature\EventFeature\TableGatewayEvent and the listener i attached did fire up during 'preInsert' event. However, i'm not able to find a way to manipulate the Laminas\Db\Sql\Insert which contain the dataset to be inserted.

```
$eventManager = new \Laminas\EventManager\EventManager();
$eventManager->attach("preInsert", function (\Laminas\Db\TableGateway\Feature\EventFeature\TableGatewayEvent $event) {
    /**
     * @var \Laminas\Db\Sql\Insert
     */
    $insertObject = $event->getParam("insert");
    var_dump($insertObject->getRawState());
});

$feature = new \Laminas\Db\TableGateway\Feature\EventFeature($eventManager);
$table = new \Laminas\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway("test_table", $adapter, $feature);

$table->insert(array(
    "name" => "hello",
    "description" => "world",
    "created_by" => NULL,
    "created_on" => NULL
));
```

The code snippet above works, and the callback function is indeed fired. I can think of another way to perform preInsert manipulation such as extending the class but i don't think that's according to what Laminas DB framework intended.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Was playing around with Laminas\Db\Sql\Insert object and you seems to be able to assign value directly as normal object property.

In my case, it's just setting the property this way.

```
    $insertObject->created_by = 1000;
    $insertObject->created_on = "2022-03-15 05:06:07";
```

Become

```
$eventManager = new \Laminas\EventManager\EventManager();
$eventManager->attach("preInsert", function (\Laminas\Db\TableGateway\Feature\EventFeature\TableGatewayEvent $event) {
    /**
     * @var \Laminas\Db\Sql\Insert
     */
    $insertObject = $event->getParam("insert");
    $insertObject->created_by = 1000;
    $insertObject->created_on = "2022-03-15 05:06:07";
    var_dump($insertObject->getRawState());
});

$feature = new \Laminas\Db\TableGateway\Feature\EventFeature($eventManager);
$table = new \Laminas\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway("test_table", $adapter, $feature);

$table->insert(array(
    "name" => "hello",
    "description" => "world",
    "created_by" => NULL,
    "created_on" => NULL
));
```